# Is it possible to use a SELECT statement within an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a SQL Access Query. The table I have is a vertical table. I want to write a SQL query that will return the name of a column, and use that returned name to insert the value into the appropriate column. My code is below:

```
INSERT INTO MONINJ
(ID_COMPLETION,
MONTH_DATE,
SELECT SWITCH(
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-WATER", "WATER_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-HOUR", "INJ_DAYS_LIQUID",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-ALKWATER", "WATER_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-BRINE", "SOLVENT_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-CO2" , "CO2_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-COND" , "COND_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-NITROGEN" , "N2_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-OIL" , "OIL_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-PROPANE" , "C3_VOLUME",
PRODUCT_TYPE = "I-STEAM" , "STEAM_VOLUME",
True, "GAS_VOLUME")
FROM C_IMPERIAL_PDEN_INJECTION_MONTH)


SELECT MASTER.ID_COMPLETION,
C_IMPERIAL_PDEN_INJECTION_MONTH.PROD_DATE,
C_IMPERIAL_PDEN_INJECTION_MONTH.VALUE
FROM MASTER, C_IMPERIAL_PDEN_INJECTION_MONTH

WHERE (MASTER.ID_COMPLETION=C_IMPERIAL_PDEN_INJECTION_MONTH.PDEN_ID);
```

I am not sure if it is possible to have a select statement in an insert statement.

Comment: this is invalid sql.  Pull the two select statements together as one and do a normal insert with select.

Comment: You can have a `SELECT` statement in an `INSERT`, but you can't put it in the list of columns. It has to be after the list of columns.

Comment: I am trying to use the switch statement to return a column name to the insert statement

Comment: What is `PRODUCT_TYPE`?

Comment: PRODUCT_TYPE is a column in one the pden_injection table. That table is a vertical table. I want to change it to a horizontal table with different column headings.

Comment: That sounds like you want a `PIVOT` query, but that doesnt make sense with the insert you're doing.

Comment: I want a pivot query, but using 2 separate tables

Comment: It seems that access has a [designer for pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-a-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc273692287).  I'm afraid that I'm not clear on how you want your data transformed based on the information provided.